# Cannot use variable in bind method

Tags: javascript, string, object, bind, ready

I have below code

```
    jsPlumb.bind("ready", function() {          
                    jsPlumb.importDefaults({
                        Anchors  : ["RightMiddle", "LeftMiddle"],
                        EndpointStyles : [{ fillStyle:'#55636b' }, { fillStyle:'#55636b' }],
                        Endpoints : [ [ "Rectangle", {width:1, height:1} ], [ "Rectangle", { width:1, height:1 } ]],
                        ConnectionOverlays  : [
                            [ "Arrow", { location: -2 , width: 15, length: 15 } ]
                        ],
                        Connector:[ "Flowchart", { stub: 10, gap:10 } ],                                
                        PaintStyle  : {
                            lineWidth:2,
                            strokeStyle:"#55636b",
                            joinstyle:"round"
                        }
                    });

                //XSSOK
                    jsPlumb.connect({ source:'start', target:'task0' });
                    jsPlumb.connect({ source:'task0', target:'end' });
                });
```

in the above code the last two lines, if I directly use in bind method then it is working.

```
jsPlumb.connect({ source:'start', target:'task0' });
jsPlumb.connect({ source:'task0', target:'end' });
```

But If I store the same value in variable and use the variable then it stopped working.

```
jsPlumb.bind("ready", function() {          
                        jsPlumb.importDefaults({
                            Anchors  : ["RightMiddle", "LeftMiddle"],
                            EndpointStyles : [{ fillStyle:'#55636b' }, { fillStyle:'#55636b' }],
                            Endpoints : [ [ "Rectangle", {width:1, height:1} ], [ "Rectangle", { width:1, height:1 } ]],
                            ConnectionOverlays  : [
                                [ "Arrow", { location: -2 , width: 15, length: 15 } ]
                            ],
                            Connector:[ "Flowchart", { stub: 10, gap:10 } ],                                
                            PaintStyle  : {
                                lineWidth:2,
                                strokeStyle:"#55636b",
                                joinstyle:"round"
                            }
                        });                 
                    sbConnections
                    });
```

Please help me to solve this problem as these values are coming from web service. I cannot hardcode it here.

Comment: sbConnections looks like it is a function or at least it should be. Otherwise that variable does not make sense.

Comment: `sbConnections` is nothing here. What should it be? If it's a function, then it's not being called. It's like opening js console and typing `42;`, it just reads the value and does nothing

Comment: I have declared 
var sbConnections = "jsPlumb.connect({ source:'start', target:'task0' });jsPlumb.connect({ source:'task0', target:'end' });";

Comment: @joe any clue? I dont find any solution for this

Comment: @CristianTraìna please provide your suggestion as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using eval function

```
jsPlumb.bind("ready", function() {          
                        jsPlumb.importDefaults({
                            Anchors  : ["RightMiddle", "LeftMiddle"],
                            EndpointStyles : [{ fillStyle:'#55636b' }, { fillStyle:'#55636b' }],
                            Endpoints : [ [ "Rectangle", {width:1, height:1} ], [ "Rectangle", { width:1, height:1 } ]],
                            ConnectionOverlays  : [
                                [ "Arrow", { location: -2 , width: 15, length: 15 } ]
                            ],
                            Connector:[ "Flowchart", { stub: 10, gap:10 } ],                                
                            PaintStyle  : {
                                lineWidth:2,
                                strokeStyle:"#55636b",
                                joinstyle:"round"
                            }
                        });                 
                    eval(sbConnections);
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Functions are first class objects in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function). In order to separate the connect from bind. I would do the following:

```
var sbConnections = function () {
    jsPlumb.connect({ source:'start', target:'task0' });
    jsPlumb.connect({ source:'task0', target:'end' });
};

// Later on
jsPlumb.bind("ready", function() {
  jsPlumb.importDefaults({
    Anchors: ["RightMiddle", "LeftMiddle"],
    EndpointStyles: [{ fillStyle: '#55636b' }, { fillStyle: '#55636b' }],
    Endpoints : [ [ "Rectangle", {width:1, height:1} ], [ "Rectangle", { width:1, height:1 } ]],
    ConnectionOverlays: [[ "Arrow", { location: -2 , width: 15, length: 15 } ]],
    Connector:[ "Flowchart", { stub: 10, gap:10 } ],                                
    PaintStyle: {
        lineWidth: 2,
        strokeStyle: "#55636b",
        joinstyle: "round"
    }
  });

  // invoke the function
  sbConnections();
});
```